# What is the role of continuity in definition of distributions?

Tags: distribution-theory

Why one can not say simply that a distribution is a linear functional on space $\mathcal D$? What is the purpose or application of topology here?

Answer (score 2):

If we remove continuity, the space $\mathcal{D}'$ of distributions certainly would not be the same:

> *The existence of linear functionals which are discontinuous on $\mathcal{D}$ may be demonstrated mathematically using the axiom of choice. However, no explicit example of these can be cited and there is very little chance of ever meeting one in practice.* ([Source](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Mathematics_for_the_Physical_Sciences/-_AuDQAAQBAJ?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=0))

In general, smaller the topology on $\mathcal{D}$, bigger the dual $\mathcal{D'}$. The topology Schwartz put in $\mathcal{D}$ is precisely the one that yields the dual with no more elements than those needed to ensure that each continuous function is infinitely differentiable:

> *ainsi nous avons introduit le moins possible d'êtres mathématiques nouveaux pour que toute fonction continue devienne indéfiniment dérivable.* ([Source](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Th%C3%A9orie_des_distributions/P1y3WtruYzAC?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=0&bsq=Th%C3%A9orie%20des%20distributions%20schwartz))

I think this can be seen as a kind of "role" of continuity (it produces an "ideal amount" of distributions).